# jquery attr add id to existing element

Tags: jquery, attr

I have a bunch of imgs inside a div with a class on them, in my JS I have a for loop that re-sizes the images to fir inside a box without stretching

```
$('.gallery img')[i].attr('id', 'img' + i);
```

This is what I tried to get each img to have its own id like 'img1' 'img2' 'img3' etc

but it seems to not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace your for loop with:

```
$('.gallery img').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'img' + i);
    // You can also add more code here if you wish to manipulate each IMG element further
});
```

This block of code loops through each IMG element with a counter i incrementing after every instance, and this counter is suffixed to the id string.

Answer (score 1):

when you do:

```
$('.gallery img')[i]
```

it returns the `DOMObject` and not a jQuery object. you will need to use `.eq()` to return the jQuery element at i:

```
$('.gallery img').eq(i).attr('id', 'img' + '"' + i + '"');
```

NOTE however, it looks like you are trying to include `"` as part of the id name. Unfortunately, single quotes and double-quotes are not valid characters for an ID name. see [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `each()` method provides on the returned jQuery object. It iterates over the elements in the returned set. The `each` method takes a callback function that will be invoked on each element in the jQuery object. The `each` method is passed the index of each element in the jQuery object as its first argument and the element itself as its second argument.

This would work:

```
$('.gallery img').each(function(index, elem) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'img' + index);
});
```